# Removing White Spaces from SQLCMD output

Tags: sqlcmd

USing SQLCMD on SQL version 2016...to remove white spaces from my output, I've tried the -W -s switches...and I still get white spaces....Here's my code 
SQLCMD -S myserver -d mydb -b -Q "exec dbo.GetiBottaItemFile"
-o "myfile" -W -s ","
-h -1 -m17

The output takes up as many spaces as the size of the field I'm selecting inthe stored procedure...I'd prefer not to do a trimr in the stored procedure on all my character fields...Any thoughts?

USing SQLCMD on SQL version 2016 and I want to remove white spaces from my output. I've tried the -W -s switches and I still get white spaces

Here's my code 
SQLCMD -S myserver -d mydb -b -Q "exec dbo.GetiBottaItemFile"
-o "myfile" -W -s ","
-h -1 -m17

The output takes up as many spaces as the size of the field I'm selecting in the stored procedure.I'd prefer not to do a rtrim in the stored procedure on all my character fields. Any thoughts?